# How can i remove bootstrap tab's hover effect?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

There is a vibration on bootstrap tab's hover event and i cant not remove it.

Here is the live demo: http://html.banjaworks.com/Gediz-Elektrik/update-info.html

You will see the vibration on hover.

Thanks.

Comment: by overriding with your custom css.

Comment: i've already tried. :/ i gave margin:0 padding:0 almost everywhere :/

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if its not working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missing is border:0px; and remove `margin: 0 !important;` from this class `.nav li:hover a`

Just add border:0px in `.nav-tabs>li>a` and you are done

So

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
```

replace this to

```
border: 0px;
```

and

```
.nav li:hover a {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    color: #00adee;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

should be

```
.nav li:hover a {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    color: #00adee;
}
```

Comment: i did what you said but its still the same.
ps: also added :hover {border:0;}

Comment: actually its not the same anymore but there is a vibration little more. thanks.

Comment: For me there is no vibration on hover. .nav-tabs > li > a in this class add margin:0 or remove margin:0 from hover class.

Comment: M just here to help but thanx :) and if it helps you then please accept as answer. Thank you